# Excel Power Query Moves old Data to the right

Tags: excel, powerquery

Currently i am copy/pasting data from one file into the data tab of a workbook. I would like to speed this up with power query. When i get data from file and drop it in, it works fine but it pushes my old data to the right and any cell references go with it.

Is there an option to overwrite what is there? i understand once it’s set up the first time as a power query function it won’t be a problem, it will just be a case of me refreshing the workbook.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I found that if i just empty the page and then add the data, The cell references do not change as there is no data to push to the right.

I wanted to answer my own question incase anyone else runs into the problem

Thanks